Compact category which is not idempotent complete
I am interested in finding an example of a category $C$ that is a compact object in the presentable category $Cat$ of small $(\infty,1)$-categories and is not idempotent complete. A category $C$ is compact in $Cat$ if and only if it is a retract of a finite colimit of $*$ and $[1] = (*\rightarrow *)$.
Following Lurie, let $Idem^+$ be the nerve of the category with two objects $X, Y$ and morphisms $f: X \rightarrow Y, g: Y \rightarrow X$ and the relation $g \circ f = Id_X$.
Let $Idem$ be the subcategory spanned by $Y$. Then a category $C$ is idempotent-complete if any functor $Idem \rightarrow C$ extends to $Idem^+\rightarrow C$, i.e. has a retract.
The category $Idem$ is not idempotent-complete but it is also not a compact object in $Cat$. However, if the answer here is correct Compact objects in undercategories and filtered colimits
then the filtered colimit in $Cat$ of idempotent-complete categories is also idempotent-complete (I should say that I could not find a reference in Lurie's latest versions of HA with this statement). Since any category $C$ is a filtered colimit of compact categories, then there must be a compact category $C_0$ that is not idempotent complete (otherwise, all categories wouuld be idempotent complete).
Question: what is an explicit example of a category $C$ that is compact but not idempotent-complete?
Ideally, I would like an expression of $C$ as a finite colimit of $*$ and $[1]$.

$Idem$ is in fact compact - it is a retract of the following finite category $C$: it has a single object $x$, and is free on an the endomorphism $e$ of $x$, the homotopy $h:e^2\simeq e$ and the higher homotopy $k: h*eh\simeq h*he$ (witnessing that the two homotopies $e^3\simeq e^2\simeq e$ are homotopic).
$C$ is clearly finite (I gave you a finite presentation, which amounts to a way of writing it as an iterated pushout of $[1]$'s and $[0]$'s), and that $Idem$ is a retract of $C$ follows from HTT's Proposition 4.4.5.20 (beware that this proposition, as well as the example 4.4.5.19 and the following corollary 4.4.5.21 which you mention is absent from the earlier versions of HTT, but it is in the most recent one) - you use 4.4.5.20 to build a map $Idem \to C$ sending the idempotent on the left to $e$, and then the composite $Idem\to Idem$ is an idempotent in a $1$-category, so to see that it is exactly the identity is just a verification on arrows.
It follows also that $C$ itself is not idempotent complete, so this gives you an explicit finite example.

Thanks! This seems to imply that $K$ itself is not idempotent complete. By your argument, $Idem$ is a retract of $K$, and hence a filtered colimit of $K$. If $K$ were idempotent complete, then by Lurie's result, $Idem$ would also be idempotent-complete. So $K$ is a finite colimit of $*$ and $[1]$ (not just a retract) and is not idempotent-complete, which is even better than what I asked for!

Yes, that's what I wrote in the last sentence :)

(though it's easier to prove that idempotent complete categories are closed under retracts than under filtered colimits)
